# ed command: Delete from line 1 until the first blank line

Tags: ed

I came across this code from a textbook; the book only says that `1,/^[ ]*$/d`
means “Delete from line 1 until the first blank line.” What does each character specifically mean?

```
ed $1 << EOF
    1,/^[ ]*$/d
    w
    q
EOF
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`1,/.../` means the range from the 1st line to a line matching the pattern between the `/`.

`/^[ ]*$/` matches a line that contains 0 or any number of spaces `[ ]*` from the beginning `^` to the end `$` of the line.
*It is unclear if the code in the question is intentional and if it is an exact copy from the book. Brackets around a single space are not necessary. Maybe the original author wanted to have a space and a tab character between the brackets, which could be replaced with the character class `[[:blank:]]`.*

`d` is the command to delete the line

`w` write the file

`q` quit the editor

Those commands are sent to `ed` via a [here document](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/117549), indicated by the `<< EOF`. The `EOF` string is a semi-arbitrary name that is paired to the other `EOF` four lines down. Leaving the `EOF` unquoted means that any variables in the intervening lines will be expanded.

The other thing to note here is the example's unquoted `$1`. The `ed` command/script will execute against the first positional parameter (argument to the script or function) **subject to further whitespace splitting and filename generation**. The argument really should be quoted. For further reading, see [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) and [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells).

Comment: Assuming the `[  ]` _does_ contain a space and a tab, then it could be replaced by `[[:blank:]]`, which would allow "blank" characters.  The line is, in a sense "blank" if it contains only characters matching `[[:blank:]]` (or contains nothing).  I'm not certain if this was tho textbook's intention, i.e. the connection between its "blank line" and `[[:blank:]]`, or whether it was just _my_ mind making that connection.

Comment: And, if the brackets contain only a space (rather than a space and a tab), then they (the brackets) can be omitted: just do ``1,/^ *$/d``.

Answer (score 3):

#### Command and input

The `$1` is the file name to be edited and everything between the EOFs are commands to `ed`.

#### Blow by blow description of `1,/^[ ]*$/d`

- `1,` start from line `1` *and in this case continue until first occurrence of search string*
- `/` indicates we are about to search for a string
- `^` indicates we want to match the start of the line in the file
- `[` indicates we are about to specify many characters
- '' we want to match a space - normally there would be more characters here
- `]` finished specifying characters
- `*` we want to match 0 or more spaces (or whatever characters between `[]`)
- `$` until the end of the line in the file
- `/` closing the search
- `d` delete the line

Then the next line `w` writes the changes, and `q` quits `ed`.

#### Effect

If the file's (`$1`) line one is empty or has only spaces (no tabs) then it will be removed.

Comment: (1) No, ```1,g/^[ ]*$/d``` is not the same as ```1,/^[ ]*$/d```.  ```1,g/^[ ]*$/d``` is the same as ```1g/^[ ]*$/d``` (i.e., the comma doesn’t change anything); that command deletes the first line if it is “blank”, but no others. (2) What are you saying about “you need to skip to the last line specified?”

Comment: (1) I did say *in this case* (2) 1,3 won't work unless you enter the `ed` command `3` beforehand.

Comment: (2) to clarify.... `3` goes (skips) to the nth line.

Comment: (1) No, `1,g/^[ ]*$/d` is not the same as `1,/^[ ]*$/d`.  They will produce the same result if the first line of the buffer is “blank”.  Since the question does not present any sample input (buffer contents), I don’t understand how you can justify saying “in this case”.  (2) I understand that, if `3` is typed as a command into `ed`, it will move you to line 3.  But you *don’t* need to do that before running a command that begins `1,3`. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  It is, of course, true that ``ed`` is a line editor, the ``ed`` command `3` will skip to line 3, and the `g` command is very useful.  I see very little else in your “**Notes** that is correct.

Comment: Point taken, I've remove the note

Comment: `1,/search/` is a range; it does not (necessarily) operate only on line 1. The important part there is the comma.

Comment: ok, changed `1,` to specify that it's a range